# Accesing shadow root inside a function

Tags: javascript, html, this, web-component

I have created simple web components using vanilla javascript as per the

The problem is on my `hideNonVisibleDivs()` i want to access `shadowRoot`

Here are my functions.

```
var visibleDivId = null;
var i, divId, div;

console.log('shadowroot', this); // display the global shadow root element

function divVisibility(divId) {
     hideNonVisibleDivs.bind(this)(divId); //binding this context
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs(divId) {
    //I want to access a shadow root here using this
    console.log('shadowroot', this); //undefined
}

var panels = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("#tab-info> .share-tab")
panels.forEach(function(el) {
        divVisibility.bind(this)(this.getAttribute('custom-id')); //bind this context

    });
});
```

What is Expected?

Inside `hideNonVisibleDivs(divId)` I want to access the shadowRoot as that of out side function (the global shadowroot ) meaning this.

Comment: Step 1 in the documentation you linked says to create a class using JavaScript class syntax. Where is your class?

Comment: @Pointy do you need all the code here ? the point is how do I access the global shadowRoot which is accessible outside my functions

Comment: A shadow root is not a global concept; it's part of a component.

Comment: I have solved the issue anyway

Comment: You might have solved it; but the use of ``bind`` tells me you most likely do not understand scopes and methods in classes. Your ``divVisibilty`` is a function, not a method on a class. Had it been a method you would have gotten the correct 'this' scope for free, without any _oldskool_ ``bind`` mumbo-jumbo. That is why we ask for the complete Web Component; then we can spot where your experienced JavaScript skills do not use modern patterns.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can offer is to stop using `this`.
The meaning of `this` changes with every function call, which is why you are having trouble understanding what it refers to at any point in your code.

For example, your `divVisibility()` function cannot work.

```js
console.log( 'shadowroot', this ); //{this} is a shadowroot

//...

function divVisibility(divId) {

     //shadow root {this} cannot be accessed at all from here

     hideNonVisibleDivs.bind(this)(divId); //binding this context
                           //^Refers to divVisibility

}
```

Try rewriting your code without using `this` anywhere. Instead, use a variable name, such as 'shadowroot'. (Without knowing your code, I do not know how useful this advice is, unfortunately.)

Comment: u didnt provide solution at all and check first web components before adding ur asnwer

Comment: @TheDeadMan the problem is the meaning of `this` changes inside divVisibility(). If he stops using `this`, his code will work. (As I said in my solution.)

Comment: don't worry I have solved the issue

Comment: @TheDeadMan Please post and accept your answer, or remove your question.